# Using @property with the ndb datastore in google app engine

Tags: google-app-engine, python-2.7, google-cloud-datastore, app-engine-ndb

Code below shows what I would normally do in a python program.

```
class LogOnline(ndb.Model):
    _timeOnline = ndb.DateTimeProperty(default=None)

    @property
    def timeOnline(self):
        return self._timeOnline

    @timeOnline.setter
    def timeOnline(self, dateTime):
        self._timeOnline = dateTime
        #set memcache with all current online users
        #.....
```

However this code doesn't work as app engine does not allow properties to start with a '_'
Also I feel this type of architecture could be bad practice as it could provide problems when doing queries on the class.

What is the best way to approach this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you could do, is make timeOnline a property without underscore, but add a [_post_put_hook](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/modelclass#Model__post_put_hook) to update memcache.

```
class LogOnline(ndb.Model):
    timeOnline = ndb.DateTimeProperty(default=None)

    def _post_put_hook(self, future):
        future.get_result() #wait untill the  PUT operation has completed
        #set memcache with all current online users
        ...
```

Comment: Thanks this was just what I was looking for, ended up using _pre_put_hook(self) in the end.

Comment: why? I don't know your exact use case, but in a _post_put_hook you can make decisions based on weather the put was successful.